# Timestamp data persistence in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nosql

In our crawling system we have 5 node cassandra cluster. I have a scenario in which I want to delete cassandra data as soon as it becomes older than x days.

Ex:

### id  |  name | created_date

```
1 | Dan      |  "2017-08-01"             
2 | Monk     |  "2017-08-02" 
3 | Shibuya  |  "2017-08-03"             
4 | Rewa     |  "2017-08-04"             
5 | Himan    |  "2017-08-05"
```

if `x = 3` Then following should be the scenario:

### id  |   name  | created_date

```
1 | Dan      |  "2017-08-01"   --------------> DELETE          
2 | Monk     |  "2017-08-02"   --------------> DELETE
3 | Shibuya  |  "2017-08-03"   -------------->(REMAIN)Latest 3 days data
4 | Rewa     |  "2017-08-04"   -------------->(REMAIN)Latest 3 days data
5 | Himan    |  "2017-08-05"   -------------->(REMAIN)Latest 3 days data
```

If new data is added then `id=3` should be deleted. 
Is there any Cassandra configuration or any approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra has a TTL feature, that allows you to specify how long each CQL cell is valid. Details are available on the [INSERT](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#insert) docs, but it also applies to UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TTL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html).

But be careful with tombstouns and compaction procedure